# Mocking an instance method call in a function

Tags: python, unit-testing

I'm currently having my first real experience writing tests by creating a unittest suite in python, and I've run into a problem with my `mock` framework.

Currently, I have a function that has a line like this:

```
def data_function():
    *Some code*
    with AccountDBConnection(account_id) as adb: # Pulling data
        data = adb.get_query_results(query)
    *Some more code*
```

I'm trying to test that the function `get_query_results` is being called correctly. In my tests, I'm attempting to test it as so:

```
@patch('package.module_that_defines_data_function.AccountDBConnection')
def test_data_function(self, mock_AccountDBConnection):
    *Other assertions*
    mock_AccountDBConnection.get_query_results.assert_called_once_with(ANY)
    *more assertions*
```

Unfortunately, whenever I try to run this test, I get an AssertionError stating `get_query_results` is never called. It most certainly is called, and I can't get it to recognize this. I think it's because the method is being called on an instance of an object that is created within the function, but I don't know how to get the mock to recognize. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: You need to mock the name as it is used in your function. As you are using it unqualified, you appear to need `@patch('module.that.defines.data_function.AccountDBConnection')`.

Comment: I am already doing that; sorry that my pseudocode isn't clear. I am already successfully mocking other methods that are called within this function, I suspect the problem with this case is that the method being called is being called from an instance created within the function.

Comment: I'm afraid you are going to have to post something reproducible.